# Fill html table based on JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I need to map the result of calling an URL into html table but I can't figure out a way to do it.

The URL to be used to get data is "https://abcdefghi/h5s5-hcxg.json". So can anyone help me with how to get data into tables from this URL ?

See my code bellow:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://abcdefghij.json",
            //force to handle it as text
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {

                //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                //and pass downloaded data
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                //now json variable contains data in json format
                //let's display a few items
                for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
                {
                    $('#results').append('<div class="name">'+json[i].name+'</>');
                }
            }
        });
</Script>
```

Comment: Want to get data from this URL above and move into table in html page using ajax or jquery.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking for, but AngularJS would make this pretty easy, but you'd have to learn the basics of AgularJS first, such as controllers, $scope, and $http. Perhaps for future web development.

Comment: This might give you a clue:                 
$('#table').append('<tr><td>' + json[i].reporting_year +'</td> <td>'+json[i].cert +'</td></tr>');

Comment: how do i check that  i am receiving  data from that link. Can i print the data in my html page.

Comment: Just use console.log(data);
And check your console by clicking F12 in your browser.

Answer (score 4):

You're not reference the json object correctly. json[i].name should really be the key you're after eg json[i].total_capacity_certified, because there is no name key in the json file your result will appear empty. The code below loops through each json object and for every key creates a new table column

```
<table id="results">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

.js

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://health.data.ny.gov/resource/h5s5-hcxg.json",
  //force to handle it as text
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data) {

    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
    //and pass downloaded data
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
    //now json variable contains data in json format
    //let's display a few items

    // we'll put all our html in here for now
    var html = '';
    for (var i=0;i<json.length;++i)
    {
      // if on first loop, create the col headers
      if(i===0){
        html += '<thead><tr>';
        $.each(json[i], function(key, value){
            html += '<td>'+key+'</td>' ;
          });
        html += '</thead></tr>';
      }

      // loop through all the json objects and for every key add a column with the value
        html += '<tr>';
        $.each(json[i], function(key, value){
          html += '<td>'+value+'</td>' ;
        });
      html += '</tr>';
    }
    // push all the html in one go to the page
    $('#results').append(html);
  }
});
```