# Read a text file containing json objects in .jsp file and populate it in HTML table

Tags: html, jsp

I want to extract a json data from a text file and want to populate that data in a HTML table .These and operations I have to inside a .jsp file. Is it possible.Can any one give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the JSON file using JSONParse API below is the code to read that :

```
 <% public void loadJSON() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("f:\\test.json"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }%>
```

from above code you will able to get JSON Object store into Some variable like `String myVar=jsonObject .toString();//which returns String` then use same into ajax function to iterate through each json element and create the table like below and import this script too : `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<table id="records_table" border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th>UID</th>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
var response=<%=myVar%>//let see this is variable where JSON String is stored 
response = $.parseJSON(response);

$(function() {
$.each(response, function(i, item) {
    $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(item.rank),
        $('<td>').text(item.content),
        $('<td>').text(item.UID)
    ).appendTo('#records_table');
    // $('#records_table').append($tr);
    //console.log($tr.wrap('<p>').html());
});
});
</script>
```

For more details : [Fill html table based on JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063401/fill-html-table-based-on-json) and try to debug line by line &  good luck